# php glob pattern match for arbitray number of digits

Tags: php, glob

Is it possible to match an arbitrary number of digits with the php glob function? I'm trying to match file names for image thumbnails that end with dimensions ranging from two to four digits.

I know I can supply a digit range, but this only matches a single character:

```
glob("thumbname-[0-9]-[0-9].jpg")
```

This will match thumbname-1-1.jpg but not thumbname-10-10.jpg, etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using: `glob("thumbname-[0-9]*-[0-9]*.jpg")`

I made a test and it works for me.

Comment: This might be good enough, although it will match thumbname-1a-1b.jpg

Comment: This seems to be the best that glob can achieve, but in the end it was too ambiguous as it would also match thumbname-2-1-1.jpg. I ended up using the RegexIterator with the regex I posted in the comments

Comment: will it work so glob("thumbname-[0-9]+-[0-9]+.jpg") ? If it shoudl be only numbers...

Comment: This is wrong. * matches everything, not just any of the previous expression. [0-9]* matches a number and then anything else. * is equivalent to .* in full regex, not *

Comment: If you want to only match `thumbname-10-10.jpg` and **not** `thumbname-1a-1b.jpg`, you want to use `glob("thumbname-*[0-9]-*[0-9].jpg")`.....however, this will also match `thumbname-a1-b1.jpg` so it's not _perfect_.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to glob(), using recursiveDirectoryIterator with a regexp

```
$Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/project/');
$Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);
$Regex = new RegexIterator($Iterator,
    '/^thumbname-[0-9]*-[0-9]*\.jpg$/i', 
    RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I may go with this method actually as the regex will give me much more control over the pattern. I've accepted the glob answer though as it was the original question.

Comment: I did go with this method in the end as the glob pattern was too ambiguous. I was finding it would match thumbname-2-1-1.jpg which removed additional files. The regex I ended up using was: '/^thumbname-[0-9]+-[0-9]+(@2x)?\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/i' as this gave me true arbritary digits and optional retina suffix

Comment: Just noticed that it seems to fail with the start of line anchor ^ seems like the full file path gets tested by the RegexIterator not just the filename?

Comment: That should be easy enoght to change, simply by removing the start anchor... the end anchor remains, and aqs the first part of the regex is a fixed "thumbnail" it should still work correctly

Answer (score 2):

You could split the numbers into different glob arrays and merge them.

For example first you take all images from 0-9 into one array:

```
$g1 =  glob('thumbname-[0-9].jpg');
```

After that you create another array which holds the numbers from 10 - 99:

```
$g2 =  glob('thumbname-[0-9][0-9].jpg');
```

Now you merge those 2 arrays into one and get all from 0-99:

```
$gResult = array_merge($g1, $g2);
```

You can extent it as much as you want just add a `[0-9]`

Answer (score 2):

The following glob pattern is complex, but works:

```
+([0-9]|!(*[a-z]*)[0-9])
```

Matches: **1**, **13**, **50000**

Non-matches: **1a**, **a1**, **1a1**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @mqrc81 thank you for your answer! Well, your solution requires extended globbing ("extglob"), as described here: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing
The PHP glob function calls the libc function glob() which AFAIK does not support extended globbing. Thus your answer won't work in PHP, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Hermann.Gruber I don't remember ever posting this anwer, but yeah you're right. Also, my solution doesn't answer the OP's question at all. It's like I only read the title.